# Dynamically Create Controls in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplate

I am pretty new to WPF. I am trying to create controls dynamically in MVVM but controls are not rendered on view. I want some number of label and textbox to be created on view.

Below is my code:

Model Code

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string KeyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string KeyValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

ModelView Code

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> propertiesList = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
    public CustomWriterViewModel()
    {

       GetMyProperties()

    }


    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Properties
    {
        get { return propertiesList; }
    }

    private void GetMyProperties()
    {
        MyModel m = new MyModel();
        m.KeyName = "Test Key";
        m.KeyValue = "Test Value";
        MyModel.Add(m);

    }
}
```

View Code(Which is user control)

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cw:MyModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Margin="10" Content="{Binding Properties.KeyName}"></Label>
                    <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding Properties.KeyValue}" Width="250"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

When view renders, I can only see empty textbox. I cannot understand what is wrong..?

Comment: You don't add anything in the `propertiesList` collection.

Comment: `MyModel.Add(m);` wat.  Helps when you step through your code with a debugger.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: added item in propertiesList but still no effect. Still the issue is same.

Comment: I feel there is some issue in data template only. I added one more item in ProperiesList. In that case I could see two empty textboxes.

Comment: You should change the bindings to simply `{Binding KeyName}` without specifying Properties. Since it is within the DataTemplate, the individual VMs are already the DataContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

The `DataTemplate` receives an individual item as its `DataContext`, therefore you only need to include item level property names within your binding paths like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cw:MyModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Label Margin="10" Content="{Binding KeyName}"></Label>
         <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding KeyValue}" Width="250"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You can identify such binding-errors in the output-window. Such errors are looking something like `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: `